# SQL- Convert Date in SQL to Integer for Case Statement

Tags: sql, date, boolean, case, azure-sql-database

I am looking to convert the dates in SQL (Azure) into an integer so I can subtract both dates. The date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD' and I want my case statement to return Null as the end date if there are more than 25 days in a month (if the difference between the end date and start date is equal to or greater than 25). The following is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [slot machines].[serial number], 
    [slot machine data].[coin in],
    'End Date' = (CASE 
                     WHEN ([slot machine data].[data calendar start date] - [slot machine data].[data calendar end date]) >= 25 
                       THEN NULL
                       ELSE [slot machine data].[data calendar end date]
                  END),
    casino.casino
FROM
    [slot machines], [slot machine data], 
    [slot machine configurations], [casino], [Themes Master List]
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using Sql Azure. Just tagged it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: and you really need to adopt the use of table aliases e.g. `FROM [slot machines] AS sm INNER JOIN [slot machine data] AS smd ON sm.id = smd.machine_id`

Comment: `select distinct is evil`! As your query is currently displayed (no where clause at all) **the comma separated list of tables will cause a massive Cartesian product**. You are most probably using select distinct to overcome substantial repetition in the result, but he reason for the repetition is how you have failed to join the tables properly.

Comment: While we're piling on, it's not good to use single quotes around column aliases. I believe you can only do that with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` off.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[slot machine data].[data calendar start date],[slot machine data].[data calendar end date]) >= 25 THEN NULL ELSE [slot machine data].[data calendar end date] END
```

Comment: Just in case the dates ever got switched or wrong order in columns I might suggest wrapping your DATEDIFF() in an ABS(DATEDIFF()) to always test a positive integer.  Then on a purely personal preference I would switch my >= 25 to <=24 and change the values in NULL/ELSE, that way if more cases are added it is a little easier to add them without defaulting to a potentially wrong value.

Comment: I understand your ABS() suggestion but if the dates did get swapped then there would be other issues that'd need to be addressed, no? What i mean is I likely wouldn't want this to return if that happened. I'm partial to < with dealing with dates as well, especially for parameters to compensate the full 23:59:59 of each day, but left it as OP had it in case there was something they were taking into consideration.

Comment: true I guess you could want to see when they are switched and it would be something I would test in my own datasets..  Dates especially with times can definitely the most challenging some times!  And then knowing when you want to add that 1 day back in to datediff or not too... Its almost as frustrating as splitting a string dynamically can be :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  Just do date arithmetic on one date:

```
(CASE WHEN [slot machine data].[data calendar start date] >= DATEADD(day, -25, [slot machine data].[data calendar end date])
      THEN [slot machine data].[data calendar end date]
 END)
```

You don't even need the `ELSE` -- `NULL` is returned if there are no matches.

Comment: I received the following error when trying your answer: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am advocating this technique but to illustrate the reasons why

```
([slot machine data].[data calendar start date] - [slot machine data].[data calendar end date]) >= 25
```

doesn't work and for getting the error in your comment:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

Is because one or both of your date fields (`[data calendar start date],[data calendar end date]`) are `DATE` datatype not another datatype like `DATETIME`.  IF both those fields where `DATETIME` then your case statement would work.

So technically you could cast your columns as `DATETIME` and `CAST` that result as an `INT`........

```
CAST((CAST([slot machine data].[data calendar start date] AS DATETIME) - CAST([slot machine data].[data calendar end date]) AS DATETIME) AS INT) >= 25
```

The last `CAST AS INT` is only necessary because you are specifically casting the other values if they are already `DATETIME` you don't have to do it......

**`DATEDIFF()` is a much easier method just thought I would point out why you had the issue with your code.**

One thing to potentially think about is using `ABS(DATEDIFF())` if your dates will ever get mixed up as far as older/newer and produce a negative result.  `ABS` is absolute value and will always result in a positive integer.

An example to illustrate being able to do what you want when values are `DATETIME`

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = GETDATE() - 10
DECLARE @Now DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @StartDateDT DATETIME = GETDATE() - 10
DECLARE @NowDT DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(@Now AS DATETIME) - CAST(@StartDate AS DATETIME) AS INT)
    ,CAST(@Now AS DATETIME) - CAST(@StartDate AS DATETIME) - 0
    ,@NowDT - @StartDateDT
```